# Bootstrap How to close all dropdown menus onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Using Bootstrap, I made a dropdown menu, inside another dropdown menu. now I'd need to close both the menus, anytime i click on a button inside them.

here is my code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`enter code here`
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Le nostre mete<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="../Canada.htm">Canada</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--FINE NAVIGATORE DESTINAZIONI-->
        <!--NAVIGATORE OFFERTE-->
        <li class="dropdown tendina-offerta">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle pacchetti" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Hotel Koh Samui<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a onclick="javascript:scrollTopiFrame();" data-toggle="pill" href="#Home"style="color:white">Phuket Home</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="javascript:scrollTopiFrame();" href="#thailandia.htm" style="color:white">Thailandia Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--FINE NAVIGATORE OFFERTE-->
        <!--TASTI DESTRA-->
        <li><a href="#">Regolamento</a></li>
        <li><a href="../contatti.htm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>Contatti</a></li>
        <li><a href="../index.htm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there anyone that could help me?
I'm a bit rusty here..

Comment: Create a snippet here or better if you could create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

To:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

This worked for me, these new attributes are the same of navigation button.